Is it possible to predict celltypes for two different batches of data directly using the FindTransferAnchors function of the signac
Now I want to integrate a scATAC data and a scRNA-seq data by signac. But I have a intractability problem is that these two batches of data are different, so even thought they are from the same mouse their barcodes are uncorresponding. This lead to strange cell types predicted by FindTransferAnchors and TransferData. So how can I handle these two datas which have different barcode.
There are 10 thousand cells in scRNA-seq(Seurat) and 3 thousand cells in scATAC data
`transfer.anchors <- FindTransferAnchors(reference = sc_1,query = atac_1,reduction ='cca')`
`predicted.labels <- TransferData(anchorset = transfer.anchors,refdata,sc_1$Celltype2,weight.reduction = atac_1[['lsi']],dims = 2:30)`




Have you tried to follow this tutorial from Satija Lab?

Yep, I refered this tutorial from Satija LAB.

If you haven't already done so consider asking on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions
